# Jenkins Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send emails using [AWS SES Simple Email Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) in my ***SpringBoot*** project
Knowing that I **verified my email** on AWS, and also created an `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY`.

Here's my code:

```
public static void amazonSimpleEmailService(String to, String subject, String htmlBody, String textBody) {

    AmazonSimpleEmailService client = AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(
                    new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)))

            .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).build();

    SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest().withDestination(new Destination().withToAddresses(to))

            .withMessage(new Message()
                    .withBody(new Body().withHtml(new Content().withCharset("UTF_8").withData(htmlBody))
                            .withText(new Content().withCharset("UTF-8").withData(textBody)))
                    .withSubject(new Content().withCharset("UTF-8").withData(subject)))
            .withSource(MAIL_ADMIN);
    client.sendEmail(request);

}
```

When  Building my code on **Jenkins** **(EC2 instance)** , this error occurs

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@55fe41ea: The requested metadata is not found at http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/, com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@2aceadd4: profile file cannot be null]
```

I doubt that am missing something but I cannot find what it is.

Comment: When you say "building", are you facing the issue in compilation?

Comment: yes compiling by jenkins

Comment: I haven't used SES, does it require to pass AWS credentials even for compilation? or is it running any Unit Tests/Testing framework and error is occurred during execution?
Also, generally, an IAM role for EC2 with required permissions on SES would be required.